# how to change npm install command in ElasticBeanstalk (Node)?

Tags: node.js, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I knew that the elastic beanstalk environments will execute the command `npm --production install`.

But, from https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4027, npm v8 (Node 16) executes scripts even when doing `npm --production install`.

According to the [npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scripts#prepare-and-prepublish), it is supposed not to do `prepare` scripts when we give some arguments like `--production`. However, the npm v8 bug still exists so that `prepare` script will be executed when I deploy my Node.js application to ElasticBeanstalk.

So, I want to change ElasticBeanstalk's command `npm --production install` to `npm install --production --ignore-scripts`. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can create a `.npmrc` file then add:

```
ignore-scripts=true
```

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/npmrc#files